# Determining whether a directed graph has a unique topological ordering?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode, topological-sort

I'm trying to design an algorithm to determine whether a directed graph has a unique topological ordering. Anyone know how to write pseudo-code for this?

Comment: Have you done anything yourself? Have you tried to google for it? Downvoted because of it. There are many algorithms to do what you want.

Comment: Sounds like a typical homework task.

Comment: Regarding your edits: Why are you actively trying to make your question sound worse than it originally was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the procedure of the topological sort, which is in short:

1. result <- [] //empty list
2. Find a node `n` which is a sink in the graph
3. remove all edges connecting to `n`, and `n` from the graph
4. result.addFirst(n)
5. if there are nodes left, return to 2

If at any iteration, at step 2 you have a choice to pick 1 from 2 or more nodes, the topological sort is not unique. If at any point, you are stuck before exhausting the graph - there is no topological sort at all.

Comment: Also if there's no sinks at step two, there's not a unique topological ordering (or, in fact, any topological ordering).

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks, added that to be explicit in the answer.